# How to convert a JSON object to array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In my application I am getting a json result from the controller, which I want to turn to array of arrays in the frontend, so I can work with the google charts api.

Currently I am using a `$.parseJSON(result)` on the string I am getting, so in the end i get this in the console :

[image]

And what i'd like to get is :

[image]

Here is the initial json string, which i get before the parseJSON part :

```
[{"rolename":"some role","perc":45.5},{"rolename":"another role","perc":36.4},{"rolename":"role three","perc":9.1},{"rolename":"role four","perc":9.1}]
```

Any tips on how can i achieve that?

Comment: Post actual data here

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES6 ( quite new cool stuff ):

```
var json=[{"rolename":"some role","perc":45.5},{"rolename":"another role","perc":36.4},{"rolename":"role three","perc":9.1},{"rolename":"role four","perc":9.1}];

var answer=json.map(el=>Object.values(el));
```

Working: http://jsbin.com/pejucoriqu/edit?console

ES5 ( compatible with a lot browsers):

```
var answer=json.map(function(el){
  var arr=[];
  for(var key in el){
    arr.push(el[key]);
  }
  return arr;
});
```

Youve got an array of objects, And you want an array of arrays. So take each element and map it with the values of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to change objects to arrays and also `Object.keys` and `map` to return only object values.

```js
var data = [{"rolename":"some role","perc":45.5},{"rolename":"another role","perc":36.4},{"rolename":"role three","perc":9.1},{"rolename":"role four","perc":9.1}]

var result = data.map(function(e) {
  return Object.keys(e).map(function(k) {
    return e[k]
  })
})
console.log(result)
```

Or with ES6 you can use arrow functions like this

```
var result = data.map(e => Object.keys(e).map(k => e[k]))
```