# Convert an array of array to array of JSON

Tags: python-3.x

I have an array of arrays such as this:

```
pl = [
        ["name1", "address1"],
        ["name2", ["address2"],
        ["name3", "address3"]
        ....
        ]
```

but I need to convert it into an array of objects:

```
pl = [
        {"name1": "address1"},
        {"name2": ["address2"},
        {"name3": "address3"}
        ....
        ]
```

I'm struggling, with no luck.

Comment: the first thing you post is already JSON. The second code you post is broken, there's an opening { but a closing ], and it's not clear what you want!

Comment: do you maybe mean "a dictionary mapping names to addresses" instead of "JSON"?

Comment: Neither input nor output is syntactically valid. If fixed, _either_ could be represented as JSON. An array of heterogenous objects isn't an easy thing to work with, though.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, sorry! I have misplaced the braces. Now it is correct

Comment: Still neither example is syntactically valid. It's an array (Python: list) of arrays to an array of _objects_ (Python: dictionary), and again _either_ can be represented as JSON. And _"struggling"_ suggests you've tried something, which is not shown - give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I need to reach the exact 2nd configuration. I tried with json.dumps, but it only adds quotes to the array. How to change the inner structure?

Comment: The _"exact 2nd configuration"_ **cannot exist**, in Python or JSON. `json.dumps` takes Python data structures (lists, dictionaries, etc.) and turns them to a JSON-formatted string. It does not _change_ the structure of the data, just serialises it.

Comment: [Will this form help with your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053773/how-to-convert-a-json-object-to-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score -2):

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Example from docs:

```py
import json
json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
```